# Ignore current class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have array of select box like below

```
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
    <option value=1>option1 </option>
    <option value=2>option2 </option>
    <option value=3>option3 </option>
    <option value=4>option4 </option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
    <option value=1>option1 </option>
    <option value=2>option2 </option>
    <option value=3>option3 </option>
    <option value=4>option4 </option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
    <option value=1>option1 </option>
    <option value=2>option2 </option>
    <option value=3>option3 </option>
    <option value=4>option4 </option>
</select>
```

Whenever I select one option from any select box , that option should be  removedfrom other select box except the currently selected selectbox. My js snippet is below

```
$('.alert_type').change(function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  $(".alert_type option[value='" + selected_value + "']").not(this).remove();

});
```

But this code remove the option from current class as well

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timus2001/06cwjn84/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting the `<select>` element, pass `this.selectedOptions[0]` to `.not()`

```js
 $('.alert_type').change(function() {
   var selected_value = $(this).val();
   $(".alert_type option[value='" 
     + selected_value + "']")
   .not(this.selectedOptions[0]).remove();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">option1 </option>
  <option value="1">option1 </option>
  <option value="2">option2 </option>
  <option value="3">option3 </option>
  <option value="4">option4 </option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">option1 </option>
  <option value="1">option1 </option>
  <option value="2">option2 </option>
  <option value="3">option3 </option>
  <option value="4">option4 </option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">option1 </option>
  <option value="1">option1 </option>
  <option value="2">option2 </option>
  <option value="3">option3 </option>
  <option value="4">option4 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Where `this` refers to the `select` tag so you need to exclude it from the `select` tag collection.

```
$('.alert_type').change(function() { 
  var selected_value=$(this).val();
  $(".alert_type").not(this).find("option[value='" + selected_value + "']").remove();
});
```

```js
$('.alert_type').change(function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  $(".alert_type").not(this).find("option[value='" + selected_value + "']").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
```

---

Or select `option` tags within the `this` context to exclude.

```
$('.alert_type').change(function() { 
  var selected_value=$(this).val();
  $(".alert_type option[value='" + selected_value + "']").not($('option', this)).remove();
});
```

```js
$('.alert_type').change(function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  $(".alert_type option[value='" + selected_value + "']").not($('option', this)).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
```

---

**UPDATE :** But I think it's better to disable the option instead of removing.

```
$('.alert_type').change(function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  $(".alert_type option").prop('disabled', false).filter("[value='" + selected_value + "']").not($('option', this)).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```js
$('.alert_type').change(function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  $(".alert_type option").prop('disabled', false).filter("[value='" + selected_value + "']").not($('option', this)).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.alert_type').change(function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  $(this).siblings(".alert_type").find("option[value='" + selected_value + "']").remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
  <option value=1>option1</option>
  <option value=2>option2</option>
  <option value=3>option3</option>
  <option value=4>option4</option>
</select>
```

1. You can use `.siblings()` with `this` context
2. Find the option with said value then hide them